# Where should I do database queries and why am I not getting the results of the queries?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm new to node.js and the express framework.

Can anyone tell me if I'm doing this correctly?

I created a database.js as a module, and the code contains:

```
var mysql = require('mysql'),
dateFormat = require('dateformat'),
db = require('./dashboard');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'root',
  password: '',
  database: 'selenium',
  timezone: '-07:00'
});

exports.selectalldate = function() {
  connection.query('SELECT * FROM date', function (err, rows, fields) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    if(rows.length > 0) {
      for(i = 0; i < rows.length; i ++) {
        rows[i].date = dateFormat(rows[i].date, "yyyy-mm-dd")
      }
      return rows;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  });
}
```

I required it in my app.js, and when I call the selectalldate() to get all the dates from the database in app.js and see what's the results. I get undefined. What am I doing wrong here?

```
var express = require('express')
  , routes = require('./routes')
  , user = require('./routes/user')
  , http = require('http')
  , path = require('path')
  , fs = require('fs')
  , file = __dirname + '/test2'
  , get = require('./routes/get')
  , db = require('./routes/database')
  ;

app.get('/dashboard', function(req, res) {
  var datee = db.selectalldate();
  console.log(datee);
  res.render('dashboard', {title: 'Selenium Dashboard', date: datee});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the asynchronous nature of Node. Everything that has networking involved (DB queries, webservices, etc) is async.

Because of this, you should refactor your `selectalldate()` method to accept an callback. From that callback you'll be able to render your template successfully with the data fetched from the DB.

In the end, it'll be something like this:

```
exports.selectalldate = function(callback) {
  connection.query('SELECT * FROM date', function (err, rows, fields) {
    if(rows.length > 0) {
      for(i = 0; i < rows.length; i ++) {
        rows[i].date = dateFormat(rows[i].date, "yyyy-mm-dd")
      }
    }

    callback(err, rows);
  });
}

app.get('/dashboard', function(req, res) {
  db.selectalldate(function(err, datee) {
    if (err) {
      // Handle the error in some way!
      return;
    }

    res.render('dashboard', {title: 'Selenium Dashboard', date: datee});
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I think I need to learn more about asynchronous and callbacks. I'm still new to javascript too. I'm able to render the template with the data now. But what if I want to do a bunch of database queries like, if(!checkIfTodaysDateExists()) { //insert todays date } then insert selenium test results into database. And what if I want to get all the selenium test results getAllTestResults() and show data in the template?

Comment: Then it'll be time to use some flow control lib; much people like [async](http://npmjs.org/package/async), I personally prefer [Q](https://npmjs.org/package/q). It's up to you, both will allow you to control such situations.